# Length of a curve in $\mathbb R^n$ smaller than the distance between two points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be s.t. $\gamma(0)=a, \gamma(1)=b$ and $\|\gamma' \|\in L^1$. How can I show that $$ \mathscr L (\gamma) = \int _0^1 \| \gamma'(t) \| dt \geq \|a-b\| \qquad ?$$

Comment: You mean bigger in the title?

Comment: @user10444 It seems he means "how would I exclude the possibility that the arc described by $\gamma$ is _shorter_ than the straight line segment between $a$ and $b$," i.e. prove that it is _longer_ or equal.

Comment: Somewhat related: [The shortest distance between any two distinct points is the line segment joining them. How can I see why this is true?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181110/).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thank you, I already knew the variational approach and was looking for an easier way to prove this fact. It seems a little bit *odd* to me there isn't a straightforward way to solve this using something like Lagrange theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false as stated. For example, let $\gamma(t)=(t,C(t))$ where $C$ is the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). Then $\|\gamma(1)-\gamma(0)\|=\sqrt{2}$ but since $\|\gamma'\|=1$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, the integral of $\|\gamma'\|=1$  is $1$.

We must assume that $\gamma$ is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity). Then the following works:
introduce the function $\varphi(t) = \langle \gamma(t),b-a \rangle$ and note that $\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=\|a-b\|^2$. Since $\varphi$ is absolutely continuous, the fundamental theorem of calculus applies to it: 
$$
\|a-b\|^2 = \int_0^1 \varphi'(t)\,dt  =   \int_0^1 \langle \gamma'(t),b-a\rangle \,dt 
\le \|a-b\|\int_0^1 \| \gamma'(t)\| \,dt 
$$
which yields the desired inequality.