# The functional take its maximal value for $y(t)=-t$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

I want to show that the functional $J(y)=\int_0^1 [y'(t) \sin{(\pi y(t))-(t+y(t))^2}]dt$

,where $y$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[0,1]$,

takes its maximal value $\frac{2}{\pi}$ for the function $y(t)=-t$.

We cannot find the derivative $J'(y)$ in order to find the maximal value because we don't know if $y'(t)$ is differentiable, right?

But how else can we deduce that $J(y)$ takes its maximal value $\frac{2}{\pi}$ for the function $y(t)=-t$?

Comment: How do you know that it has a maximum value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $J(y) = \int_0^1 L(x,y,y') \ dx$ where $L(x,y,y') = y'.\sin(\pi y) - (t + y)^2$. Then by the E-L equation, $J$ has extrema when

$$\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial y} - \cfrac{d \ }{dt}\left(\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right) = 0$$

I.e., $$\left( \pi.y'\cos(\pi y) - 2(t+y)\right) - \cfrac{d \ }{dt}(\sin(\pi y)) = 0 $$
equivalently

$$\pi.y'\cos(\pi y) - 2(t+y) - \pi.y'\cos(\pi y) = 0$$

or

$$2(t+y) = 0$$

Thus, $y(t) = -t$.

For that function $y$, $L(t,y,y') = -1 \cdot \sin(-\pi t) + 0 = \sin(\pi t)$. Hence

$$J(y) =  \int_0^1 \sin(\pi t) \ dt = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

*Added:* Now, how do we know this is a maximum?

We can bound the integral:

$$\int_0^1 y'\sin(\pi y) - (t+y)^2 \ dt \leq \int_0^1 y'\sin(\pi y) \ dt = \frac{1}{\pi} \big(\cos(\pi y(0)) - \cos(\pi y(1))\big) \leq \frac{1 + 1}{\pi} $$

Hence, for any $y$, this integral is bounded above by $2/\pi$ and for $y(t) = -t$, that bound is attained.

So actually, we didn't need to use the E-L equation after all. After we found the bound, we could have infered a function $y$ which attained the bound.

---

*Second addition:*

Let $$A = \left\{ \int_0^1 y'(t)\cdot\sin(\pi y(t)) - (t + y(t))^2 \ dt \ \big| \ y \in C^1[0,1] \right\} \ \subset \mathbb R$$

Then $2/\pi \in A$ and $2/\pi$ by the argument above is an upper bound. Hence $\max A = 2/\pi$.

Comment: Is it maybe $L=L(t,y,y')$?

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: How do you know that $J$ has a maximum and a maximizer?

Comment: @copper.hat Fair point, added.

Comment: +1: Nice. The EL approach can be misleading/dangerous if the existence is not addressed first.

Comment: @SimonS So does it hold that $\frac{\partial{y'}}{\partial{y}}=0$ ?

Comment: Yes. How is your teacher/professor expecting you to answer these questions? Using the E-L equations? If so, then surely you've seen examples working through such points. Or maybe you are expected to use inequalities only?

Comment: @SimonS We haven't done examples using the E-L equations. But could you explain me why $J$ has extrema when $\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{y}}-\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{y'}}\right)=0$ ?
$$$$
Also, if we don't use the E-L equations, and we have found the bound, how can we find the $y(t)$ for which the bound is attained?

Comment: Ok. If you haven't covered the E-L equations, then that is not what you are supposed to use. In that case, you can infer the form of $y(t)$ from our bounds. The first inequality is equality when $y(t) + t = 0$. That condition also ensure that the last inequality is also equality.

Comment: @SimonS Ok.. And why do we deduce that $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is the maximum value of $J$ and not just only the supremum?

Comment: Because it is actually attained for $y(t) = -t$.

Comment: @SimonS And why do we deduce from the fact that  it is actually attained for $y(t)=-t$ that it is the maximum value? :/

Comment: The inequalities show that for **any** continuously differentiable function $y$

$$\int_0^1 y'(t)\sin(\pi y(t)) - (t + y(t))^2 \ dt \leq \frac{2}{\pi}$$

For the function $y(t) = -t$, that bound is attained. Hence $2/\pi$ must be the maximum because (a) no greater number can be a maximum or supremum because $2/\pi$ is an upper bound; (b) no lesser number can be a max or sup because there is a function $y$ for which $J(y) = 2/\pi$.

Comment: Why can no greater number be a maximum? @SimonS

Comment: (See also the argument I just added above.) The maximum, if it exists, is unique. Moreover, we have shown for all relevant $y$ that the integral is bounded above by $2/\pi$. Hence the greatest value the maximum can have is $2/\pi$. If the maximum were greater than $2/\pi$ that would contradict the inequality bound. That is, there would exist a function $\tilde y$ such that $\int_0^1 (integrand \ with\ \tilde y) \ dt > 2/\pi$.

Comment: @SimonS I got it... Thanks a lot!!! :-)